# Encountering "Snapshot too old" error during execution of expdp command

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, export, dump

As am facing an issue while performing expdp command in my production db.(Oracle 11g in windows enviornment)

> cmd> expdp 'sys/123@PROD as sysdba' DUMPFILE=BACKUP_02082017_BACKUP.dmp LOGFILE=BakupLog_02082017_BACKUP.log SCHEMAS=A1,B2,C3,D4.. exclude=statistics consistent=y

It was taking more than 1 day to export the database sized 7GB. But my issue is that the exporting have error and shows error message

> ORA-31693: Table data object "owner"."PASSWORD_HISTORY" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
>   ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
>   ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 19 with name "_SYSSMU19_255734752$" too small

As i set my retention policy to 16500 from default 900. Even though, same error was occurring.

As i am planning to increase the retention policy up to 10 hrs ie, 36000. Is it viable? I am confused that do my undo table space is capable for this or not?

Providing some more details:

```
>  show parameter undo_%;

 NAME                                             TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------- 
undo_management                                   string     AUTO                                                                                                 
undo_retention                                    integer    16500                                                                                                
undo_tablespace                                   string     UNDOTBS1  




>  select file_name,tablespace_name,trunc(bytes/1024/1024) mb, trunc(maxbytes/1024/1024) mm
        FROM dba_data_files
        where tablespace_name = 'UNDOTBS1';

FILE_NAME                                  TABLESPACE_NAME    MB MM
--------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\APP\ADMIN\ORADATA\PROD\UNDOTBS01.DBF   UNDOTBS1          5630 32767




>Size of undo with current undo_retention :
     Actual Undo size[MBytes]:5630
     UNDO retention[Sec]:16500 
     Needed Undo Size[MBytes]:909.433359
```

I am stuck with this issue. Anyone please advice how i deal with this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 day to export 7Gb is excessive. Is the database on a remote server with crapy connectivity?

Comment: Database is on remote server but their is no issue with connectivity and the export is happening with in the server itself.

Comment: I had the same problem
The cause was LOB CORRUPTED.
After fix , expdp works fine. Script to detect error [here](https://dbpilot.net/2018/ora-1555-snapshot-too-old-due-to-corrupted-lobs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the `ORA-01555` error is `undo_retention` parameter has the lower value as compared to the time taken to complete the export with the parameter `consistent=y`(which is deprecated in 11g and should use `flashback_time` or `flashback_scn`).

Your undo retention should able to retain the undo information for the time period of export job.

For example, if you export starts at `00:00 AM` and it takes 2 hours to complete then the `undo_retention` should be set at least 2 hours if you wish to get consistent data.

I have simulated the problem in my test server.

```
[oracle@orcl expdp_dump]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Feb 8 09:41:40 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> show parameter undo

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
undo_management                      string      AUTO
undo_retention                       integer     2400
undo_tablespace                      string      UNDOTBS1
```

My undo retention is set to 40 minutes.

```
SQL> select bytes/1024/1024 from v$datafile where ts#=2;

BYTES/1024/1024
---------------
          32764
```

And my undo tablespace is 32GB large.

I tried to export one of my schemas.

```
expdp system/password directory=DP_DIR schemas=MYSCHEMA dumpfile=expdp_orcl_MYSCHEMA.dmp logfile=expdp_orcl_MYSCHEMA.log FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP
```

> Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_07" completed with 1 error(s) at Tue
>   Feb 7 22:14:46 2017 elapsed 0 01:14:39

It took 1 hour and 14 minutes. And there were moderate DML operations in the database.

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "MYSCHEMA"."MS_TABLE":"MS_TABLE."MS_TABLE_B_2005" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 84 with name "_SYSSMU84_1745672109$" too small
. . exported "MYSCHEMA"."PRORATE_EVENT"              8.789 KB       4 rows
. . exported "MYSCHEMA"."PRORATE_RULE_GROUP"         5.945 KB       1 rows
. . exported "MYSCHEMA"."ORACLE_JOB_METADATA"            0 KB       0 rows
```

And I got the `ORA-0155` error.

Then I increased the undo retention to 1 hour and 20 minutes.

```
SQL> alter system set undo_retention=4800;

System altered.
```

And again I tried to export the schema.

```
expdp system/password directory=DP_DIR schemas=MYSCHEMA dumpfile=expdp_orcl_MYSCHEMA.dmp logfile=expdp_orcl_MYSCHEMA.log FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP
```

> Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_07" successfully completed at Wed Feb
>   8 22:15:52 2017 elapsed 0 01:15:45.

And there was no `ORA-01555` anymore.

Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 182.9 GB

and the actual file size is 141 GB.

Why the difference in estimation and the actual size of the dump file? Look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162473/difference-in-database-dump-file-size/162489#162489) post for the answer.

Regarding the time taken to complete the export. Try to use the following parameters.

Parallel

DIRECT=y

Also, try to gather data dictionary statistics before starting the export job-

```
SQL> connect / as sysdba
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
SQL> exec dbms_stats.lock_table_stats (null,'X$KCCLH'); 
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
```

**Futher Readings:**

Poor Performance With DataPump Export On Large Databases (Doc ID 473423.1)

[Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624)

Comment: My undo tablespace is 5.5GB large.ANd I am setting my undo_retention to 36000 ie, 10hrs. Is this cause any kind of issue to my DB?

Comment: That's quite strange, you got to trace your expdp process what actually it is doing behind the scene. As I have shown you it took 1 hour to export 141GB schema. Don't just increase it without knowing the actual problem.

Comment: Add `trace=1FF0300` parameter in expdp command and see which step is taking more time.

Comment: Sometimes, if I don't need a full export, I just export each schema and that tends to avoid this error.  Not always an option, but can work if migrating schemas and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to increase the max_extents of your rollback segment highlighted and all others with the same max_extents, OR offline them and leave